# Can interpreted language be natively multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading

First of all, let me clarify the terms in order to avoid any possible misunderstandings.

Language is considered to be **compiled** when a program written in it's source code cannot be run directly without additional steps **under normal conditions**. That means it's usually and normally done that way. Technically we have online REPLs for C++ which let you run C++ code line by line. That is not considered normal conditions, because normally (i.e. in production usage) it is preprocessed, assembled, compiled and linked. Same goes for Java, technically you can write bytecode by hand and then have it directly executed by the virtual machine. Is it normally done that way? The answer is no.

A few examples of what is considered a compiled language:

```bash
g++ -Wall -pedantic thread.cpp

java c Thread.java
jar cfm Thread.jar manifest.txt

cargo build --release
```

By contrast, language is considered to be **interpreted** when a program written in it's source code is usually run directly, without any additional steps **under normal conditions**. I don't care if it's JIT-compiled by some state-of-the-art technology that makes it look like it's interpreted. If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, you know the saying.

A few examples of what is considered an interpreted language:

```bash
python3 thread.py
node thread.js --trace-opt
```

**Multithreading** is considered as a process of executing multiple threads simultaneously i.e. **concurrent** execution of two or more parts of the program at the same time. So, there must at least be:

- true parallelism (execution in two different threads happens really in parallel, at the same time, not some kind of sneaky asynchronicity, when one is actually happen **after** another but it's so optimized that it looks like it runs simultaneously)
- an ability to spawn multiple threads in one source code file that have direct access to shared variables
- threads spawn from the main thread must have **exactly the same** functionality, without any limitations
- possibility of race condition as a consequence might exist
- some kind of locks to prevent it
- an ability to observe said threads by OS means

A language must have **native** multi-threading. That is, it's directly built-in in the language itself. What is **not** considered a **native** multithreading:

- some kind of third party library you need to install via package manager
- some non-standard implementation of the language that runs in some kind of environment
- not coming from the language itself, but from it's environment, like Browser API for example, which provides workers for JavaScript in the Browsers

All interpreted languages that I know of are single threaded. Some of them are limited by GIL (like Python and Ruby), others by the runtime environment (like JavaScript). By contrast all compiled languages like C++, Java, Rust support multi-threading.

Question is: can interpreted language be multithreaded? If it can, please name an example. If it can't is there any computational reason for that?

Comment: All of these support multi-threading, using the ancient pattern known as "process group".

Comment: @Ben Voigt they actually do not. Like for example Python docs clearly state "In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once". JavaScript is a well-known single-threaded language as well.

Comment: Javascript supports multithreaded execution now, via [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). So apparently the answer is *yes*.

Comment: @John Wu web workers have nothing to do with JS, they're part of Web API. I don't want to go into too much detail here because 1) comments' section are too narrow 2) we're here not to deny the obvious fact that JS is [by definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) a single threaded language. Even if we consider web workers being JavaScript it's just running a couple of single-threaded programs in separate containers and passing messages between them. It is by no means a multi-threading.

Comment: @tnsaturday: The CPython docs that you quoted already prove that Python is multi-threaded. Because if Python *weren't* multi-threaded, then only being able to run one thread at a time wouldn't make sense: there is only one thread. The fact CPython explicitly documents the restriction that only one of multiple threads can run at a time obviously means that there can be multiple threads, ergo, Python is multi-threaded.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag again, I don't really want the level of this discussion sink so low that I have to quote Wikipedia, but multithreading is by definiton a process of executing multiple threads simultaneously i.e. concurrent execution of two or more parts of the program at the same time.

Comment: @tnsaturday: that's not true. Hop in your Delorean, time travel back to 2001 or earlier, and you'll find mutlithreading existed, but most computers only had a single CPU, which meant that only a single thread was executing at any given time. What threading provides, even on a single CPU, is the means to abstract away seemingly concurrent tasks without having to melt your brain with `select()` and other management to keep track of the two lines of computation, and sharing resources instead of having to jump through a bunch of IPC hoops with multiprocessing.

Comment: In other words, don't confuse actually executing two sets of instructions at the same instant in time, with vague concurrency as in being able to do two high level tasks vaguely concurrently allowing yourself to not sweat the details of scheduling things back and forth.

Comment: Your definition of "interpreted" is at best shaky. No language, except machine code, is run "without additional steps". There is always some sort of translation going on. Jitting is at least considered as a form of interpretation by wikipedia. While javascript used to be interpreted, by now jitting should be more common, so what is "normal" can, and has, changed.

Comment: There is also "GIL-free Python" https://github.com/colesbury/nogil which really does execute on multiple threads on the same time.

Comment: Relevant: [PEP 684 – A Per-Interpreter GIL](https://peps.python.org/pep-0684/) is supposed to be coming soon.

Comment: Also: [PEP 703 – Making the Global Interpreter Lock Optional in CPython](https://peps.python.org/pep-0703/)

Comment: When you said "A language must have native multi-threading. That is, it's directly built-in in the language itself." your question became a farce - by that definition C is not multithreaded since it relies on OS system calls to provide threading - ego - no language is multithreaded.

Comment: What has the "ability to spawn threads or processes" , to do with "compiled or interpreted" ?  shell scripts have been doing such all along.

Comment: @DavidT I never said that C is multithreaded. Read my question carefully

Comment: *"not some kind of sneaky asynchronicity"* - that's not a particularly reasonable criteria. Many aspects of computers are inherently serial even at the hardware level, even if there are multiple CPUs - for example, bus lines, hard disks, etc.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an interpreted language". You can interpret C, and you can AOT compile Python. Languages are abstract specifications of things, which can have 0 or more implementations, each of which can take completely different approaches to the same thing (e.g. compare CPython, Jython, IronPython and Pylir)

Comment: @Steve for the sake of example, I made it clear that a parallel computations MUST be possible

Comment: @Alexander again, I made it pretty clear in the question what is considered interpreted. You can't interpret C under normal conditions. You just can't. And you don't AOT compile Python usually as well. You just type in `python3 script.py` in a shell of your choice and that's it. Regarding implementations, I made it clear about standard (most popular) implementation. You can implement interpreted Haskell in your garage, I don't care. Neither I do care about PyJyLirs or some other custom shop. It was all made clear in the question. Next time please do bother yourself with reading before writing.

Comment: @tnsaturday, yes but it isn't really possible on conventional hardware, within the realms of what would be regarded as a single machine. You could orchestrate multiple PCs across a network of course, but there are few problems to which such solutions are relevant, and therefore mainstream programming languages don't provide these facilities. (1/2)

Comment: Even multicore systems, they don't exist because parallel is better for program execution per se, they exist because hardware makers hit the limit of CPU frequency for single core execution, and therefore to continue improving performance had to find a way to divide up the total processing work a single machine performs in normal operation. It's done largely seamlessly, at the OS level, the programmer does not usually have to reckon with it - and even if he does, he can't guarantee things are actually parallel and not just "sneakily asynchronous". (2/2)

Comment: @Steve what you say has actually nothing to do with reality. Almost all modern computer games for example make heavy use of multiple CPU cores. You can check it very easily: just launch something like Battlefield 1 and check your resource monitor. It will show AT LEAST two CPU cores under load. That is BY DEFINITION parallel and done on conventional hardware. And that's what I actually want - to make parallel computations on multiple cores.

Comment: @tnsaturday I actually did read your question, and even upvoted it because it’s interesting. I said what I said because the questions emphasis on *languages* and not *implementations*, is a red herring, IMO.

Comment: @tnsaturday, no it isn't parallel by definition, because whenever the game for example reads from disk, it's serial by definition (because of the physical nature of the hardware). You're actually considering only a small subsystem when talking about the CPU cores. Even main memory access is fully serial - access is shared between the cores in a "sneakily asynchronous" way.

Answer (score 5):

> Question is: can interpreted language be multithreaded?

Yes.

> If it can, please name an example.

Python.

Ever since 2003 the
[Twisted](https://pypi.org/project/Twisted#history)
community has been leaning pretty hard
on python's ability to interleave threads of execution
within a single address space.
Given GIL constraints, the focus has been on I/O-bound processing,
such as seen in a web server.

With modern
[asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)
we see threads `await`ing futures all the time.

Compute-bound data science workloads that rely on BLAS-based
libraries like {numpy, pandas, scikit-learn}
will often release the GIL. That way sibling threads
can do work while a solver written in a compiled
language is keeping other cores busy.

---

Your line of questioning seems directed at
compute-bound {C++, java, rust} programs like this:

Init common `counter` to zero.

Spawn thread 1, with private `i` variable:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 900; i++) { counter += 1 }
```

Spawn thread 2, with private `j` variable:

```
    for (j = 0; j < 900; j++) { counter += 1000 }
```

And then we wonder if, once the dust settles,
we will see a value of 900900.
If not, we worry about using semaphores or other IPC
to protect the "increment" critical region.
We might also add `sleep(0)` or similar voluntary "yield" statements.

We can write such programs in python, as well.

The difference is, the language-level GIL prevents
conflicting counter updates.
It is either a blessing or a curse, take your pick.
Because a mutex, outside of app developer control,
is held while each app thread runs,
a whole class of potential bugs has been avoided.
That is the tradeoff python made long ago,
and which we still live with.

Is this the threading behavior OP desires?
Probably not.

Is the bytecode interpreter running multiple threads?
Absolutely.

Comment: What your "counter" example points at it the language's memory model. Some languages have an explicit memory model, which explains how concurrent access to objects is handled. For example, Java guarantees that variable assignments are atomic, C guarantees you'll be accidentally invoking UB. "Scripting" languages have a more complex data model, so specifying a useful memory model is difficult without breaking old code. Python's memory effectively ensures atomicity for most opcodes. But increments involve multiple opcodes (`a += b` ≈ `a = a.__iadd__(b)`), making data races possible here…

Comment: @amon I think "guaranteeing UB" is an oxymoron - the whole point of UB is that it doesn't guarantee _anything_. Famously, it was once remarked that undefined behaviour cloud mean the compiler will "make demons fly out of your nose" - but it might also document and implement a much more sane result for that code. So what you're really saying is "the C standard doesn't define a memory model covering this situation, but a particular compiler might do so".

Comment: @IMSoP I'm being a bit facetious. While C (since C11) is one of the few languages with a thoroughly defined memory model for atomics/multithreading (to the point that other language's memory model often just says "whatever C does"), the language famously lacks guardrails. Shared memory will exhibit defined behaviour when explicitly using the atomics library or guarding accesses with mutexes, but nothing will warn you if you forget that. Some langs like Erlang solve this via a shared-nothing architecture, others like Rust with stronger type systems. Java/Python only ensure memory safety.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR - Java byte Code - i.e. you are hand coding the byte code and running it on the JVM - It's interpreted by the JVM and provides full support for native threads and locking primitives.

--

Operating systems typically provide the ability to share memory between processes and also share certain types of locks as a result it is reasonable to say that two processes that are sharing state and are additionally controlling access to the shared state via synchronization primitives are a form of multithreading - you have multiple threads (that happen to be in different processes) that are communicating.

"Interpreted Language" is more difficult to define - personally I am happy with the definition that: if it isn't directly executed on the CPU it's interpreted. That does leave some gaps with respect to JIT compilers, however for this argument we can just assume you can disable the JIT so the code remains purely interpreted.

With these definitions, any language that is not compiled to native code and can use OS level shared memory + synchronization primitives can be considered to be both interpreted and multithreaded (including the example I started this post with).

--

If you want a different argument, please provide two requirements:

- One that is a defining attribute of all multithreaded applications.
- One that is a defining attribute of all interpreted languages.

Such that you believe that both could not be implemented in the same "toy" language invented just to prove this point. I cannot think of any such pair of requirements.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good question. At a high-level your observation seems correct, i.e.: that what people tend to think of as 'compiled' languages tend to have more or better support for 'true concurrency' where two or more threads can be executing at the same time. However, there are a few minor misconceptions here that are leading you to an incorrect conclusion.

I don't want to get too deep into the details of this but first off, the whole concept of interpreted versus compiled is very fuzzy.  I don't think there's a precise way to define the difference.  You point to Java as compiled but you should understand that the first thing that happens when you run a newly written CPython script is that it compiles the program into a folder called `__pycache__`.  If you look in that folder, you will find .pyc files.  Those contain the compiled python bytecode that is actually executed by the runtime.  This essentially no different than the way Java works, other than that it's automatic instead of requiring a separate compile step before running.

You asked for an example of an interpreted language that allows for true multithreading and the immediate thought that I had was: [Jython](https://www.jython.org/). I consider the project to be defunct, but I used in extenively in the past. Jython is basically a java library that implements a Python interpreter/runtime on top of the Java interpreter.  The crucial thing here is that it does not have a GIL so it has the same multithreaded capabilities as a vanilla Java program.  There are other 'interpreted' languages such as [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) that are implemented in Java which (AFAICT) are also able to use Java multi-threading capabilities.  So even if we set aside the debate over 'compiled' versus 'interpreted', I think this is proof that there's nothing inherent that prevents an 'interpreted' language from supporting true concurrency.

The GIL (in Python anyway) is a feature.  It was introduced to eliminate the possibility of a lot of nasty problems that come with multithreading.  It might also have been a way to avoid creating the kind of proper memory model needed to make multithreading reliable across platforms.  If you have time, you can learn more about the GIL in this video: [Understanding the Python GIL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s)

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, it seems nobody has mentioned Erlang, *the* concurrent language, yet.

Erlang is interesting in regards to this question, because besides being fully interpreted (not JITted!), it provides **three** kinds of concurrency.

The first one is the logical concurrency, where the interpreter will occasionally switch which task it's running. The second one is true multithreading, and the third one is running different tasks of the same program on different processes, or even separate physical computers. From a code point of view, there is no visible difference.

What makes this possible (and avoids the problems with Python's GIL) is that each task has, effectively, a separate address space, with separate garbage collectors and such. They can only communicate by copying data between tasks. This is what allows it to run on separate processes/machines, and why it scales so well; there are no race conditions relating to shared mutable state, because there is no shared mutable state.

And that brings me to the actual answer to your question: most interpreted languages (in the sense you use the word, which is non-standard) are meant to be high-level, and dealing with locks and shared memory is a very low-level way of doing concurrency. So most languages that provide that are low-level.

Most high-level languages provide a higher-level abstraction for concurrency, which you wouldn't really call "language-level multithreading", in the sense of shared mutable state, even if it accomplishes the same things and is implemented in terms of it.

Go is a great example of this; it's compiled but meant to be high-level, and while you *can* use it with mutable state and locks, the primary kind of concurrency it encourages is sending immutable data to tasks.

So it's not a matter of whether it's possible or not; it's about what those languages are designed for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why an interpreted language shouldn't be multi-threaded, except that your interpreter needs to be multithreaded as well, or you are in the same situation as a multithreaded compiled language on a single core machine (without hyperthreading).

A singlethreaded interpreter could switch between the threads of your interpreted language, but you wouldn't be able to take advantage of multiple cores. Multiple threads can be useful even on a single threaded machine, for example to perform other tasks while one thread performs an http request.

As an example, a Java bytecode interpreter may need to load a Java class. That should be done only once. If you had a multithreaded interpreter, and they decided in the same nanosecond to load the same class, then they would need to synchronise so that one interpreter thread loads the class, and the other interpreter waits for it to finish. And that's what actually happens because a JVM is supposed to run multithreaded.

But it does come at development cost. So the interpreter for your favourite language might have to be modified very carefully to be able to run multithreaded. Just like your processor had to be designed very carefully to run multithreaded without problems.